# Mobile menu does not show properly on some iphones and ipads

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, menu, prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.6 with a custom theme. I have done some little changes here and there on the theme mostly just color and font on the css file. The mobile menu works perfectly on all android that I've tested but for some reasons, it does not work properly on some Apple devices. On an ipad 2 IOS 7.1.2, the menu background shows but the content does not. On an iphone 4 IOS 5.0.1, some of the content show, some don't. But then, it work great on an iphone 4 IOS 7.1.2.

I have no idea how to fix such problem as I have no clue what is going on. Has any one experience this problem or know the reason. Please help me out.

Here is the link to the site: www.halivu.com (it's not fully done, I have not finished with the content :D).

Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

try to emulate the devices in Google Chrome.

[image]

All menu div tags are empty. Check your mobile settings in prestashop backend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it on other phones and it works. How could you explain that? I want to know what is the cause for the unstable. It just doesn't work on some apple devices and it work just fine on android.

Comment: I tried the emulation but it does show everything correctly. Please check the image. http://halivu.com/imgs/ipad3-4%20emulation.jpg So that even on google emulation, it is different from mine and your. This really drive me crazy.

Comment: You need to reload the page after starting the emulation mode.

Comment: Yes I did, actually a couple time